# Residues and poles proof

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Let the degree of the polynomials $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots+a_nz^n$
>   $a_n\neq0$ and $Q(z)=b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2+\cdots+b_mz^m$ $b_m\neq 0$ be such that $m\geq n+2$. Show that
>   if all the zeros of $Q(z)$ are interior to a simple closed contour C,
>   then $$\int_C\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} \, dz=0$$

I am lost on how to show it $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ are polynomials, then the ratio is analytic in all the points except where $Q(z)=0$. If $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ be analytical in all the points on the contour or inside, so I could tell straight that the integral is zero, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ are polynomials, they are entire. So $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is complex differentiable at all points $z$ such that $Q(z) \neq 0$. Since $C$ contains a zero of $Q$, $P/Q$ is not analytic inside $C$. Therefore, you cannot apply Cauchy's integral theorem to deduce $\int_C P(z)/Q(z) \, dz = 0$. However, you may use the residue theorem.

Let $r > 1$ be sufficiently large so that the circle $|z| = r$ contains the all the zeros of $Q$ and

$$\frac{|b_{0}|}{r^m} + \frac{|b_1|}{r^{m-1}} + \cdots + \frac{|b_{m-1}|}{r} < \frac{|b_m|}{2}.$$

Thus

$$|Q(z)| \ge r^m\left(|b_m| - \frac{|b_{m-1}|}{r} - \cdots - \frac{|b_1|}{r^{m-1}} - \frac{|b_0|}{r^m}\right) \ge \frac{|b_m|r^m}{2}$$

for all $z$ on the circle $|z| = r$. Also, on the same circle, $|P(z)| \le C_n r^n$, where $C_n = n \max\{|a_0|,\ldots, |a_n|\}$. By the ML-inequality,

$$\tag{*}\left|\int_{|z| = r} \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\, dz\right| \le \frac{4\pi C_n}{|b_m|r^{m-n-1}}.$$ On the other hand, the residue theorem gives

$$ \int_C \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\, dz = 2\pi i\sum (\text{residues of $P/Q$}) = \int_{|z| = r} \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\, dz.\tag{**}$$

Since $m \ge n + 2$, the expression on the right-hand side of $(*)$ tends to $0$ as $r \to \infty$. Hence by $(**)$,

$$\int_C \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\, dz = 0.$$

Comment: Is it straightforward to show that $C$ is homotopic to a large circle (avoiding the poles)?

Comment: @copper.hat you don't need $C$ to be homotopic to a circle, but I think I see where you might've thought of that. I'll make a small edit.

Comment: But isn't this a rather more complicated argument than what is needed? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy what do you mean?

Comment: I just meant that it can be done as in my posted answer, which seems a whole lot simpler. (But just how simplicity is to be measured may not be very simple.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy it assumes that one knows the change of variable formula for contour integration. Also, the contour $C$ changes after the transformation; $C$ is not necessarily invariant under inversion. In any case, typical complex analysis courses avoid the discussion about change of variables in the complex setting, so I believe it's useful to resort to a careful use of the residue theorem (or otherwise use residue theorem for residues at infinity, which will simplify the proof greatly).

Comment: Oh.... I'd been assuming $C$ was a circle.....  I'll edit the answer a bit.

Comment: Changes of variables like that I may have been treating as free of charge.  Proving a thing like that is definitely not the interesting part of the subject, for my tastes.  Anyway, I've edited the answer so that I don't assume so much about the curve.

Comment: @MichaelHardy the inversion may also affect the orientation. For if $C_r$ denotes a circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin, then after inversion, the contour becomes $-C_{1/r}$.

Comment: It _does_ affect the orientation.  But minus zero is zero.

Comment: @MichaelHardy right, but I think it's worth mentioning, since the OP might pass that by.

Comment: Good point.  I'll add it.

Comment: Done. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$and now I've edited to note the fact that although the change in orientation changes the sign, that is canceled by the $-1$ in $dz=-dw/w^2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Are you sure that the correct bound for $|P(z)|$ is $C_nr^n$ and not $nC_nr^n$?

Comment: @MathewJames that was a typo, it should read $C_n = n\cdot \max\{\lvert a_0\rvert,\ldots, \lvert a_n\rvert\}$. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align}
z & = \frac 1 w \tag 1 \\[10pt]
dz & =\frac{-dw}{w^2} \tag 2
\end{align}
$$
\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} = \frac{P(1/w)}{Q(1/w)}
$$
Multiply the top and bottom both by $w^m$ to get a polynomial in $w$ in each of those two places.  Since $m\ge n+2$, you get a factor of $w^2$ in the numerator that cancels the $w^2$ in $(2)$.

The zeros of the denominator are now outside the image of the curve $C$ because the transformation $z\mapsto 1/z$ turns the plane inside-out.  It also changes the orientation of $C$, thus multiplying the integral by $-1$, and that sign change is canceled by the $-1$ in $(1)$ above. But since the integral ends up being $0$, the sign doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Note: This essentially shows that the residue at infinity is 0, and the sum of all residues on the complex plane is equal to the residue at infinity.