# Sum over all residues is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f$ be a rational function mapping to $\mathbb{C}$, $$f(z)=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$$ with $\deg P\leq \deg Q -2$. I want to show that the sum over all residues is zero.

What am I asked to show? I think: The only singularities are in the zeros of $Q$. So if $N_Q$ is the set of zeros of $Q$ I have to show $$\sum_{q\in N_Q} Res(f,q)=0,$$haven't I? Since there are max. $\deg Q$ many zeros of $Q$, the sum is finite.

In order to show the statement - how can I use the $\deg$ condition?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305531/residues-and-poles-proof/1305571#1305571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Let $R_0$ be a radius such that all poles of $f$ are inside the circle $C_{R_0}: |z|=R_0$.

Then, by the residue Theorem 
$$\int_{C_R} f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{q\in N_Q} Res(f,q)$$

for all $R > R_0$.

What happens when you take 
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_R} f(z) dz ?$$

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I just wonder why you have not taken the winding number, e.g. $\int_{C_R} f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{q\in N_Q} w(C_R,q)Res(f,q)$?

Comment: @N.Sch Because if $R>R_0$ all the residues are inside the circle $C_R$ and hence all the winding numbers are 1.

Comment: Ah, sure! Thank your! I think you need the degree condition to show that the integral tends to zero. But I don't get the details.

Comment: @N.Sch Use the fact that $$\left| \int_{C_R} f(z) dz \right| \leq 2 \pi R M$$ where $M$ is the maximum of $f(z)$ on $C_R$. Combine this with the degree condition ;)