# Evaluating matrix function $f$ by summing over poles of $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $f(x)$ is some function with simple poles at points $a_i$ and $A$ is a square matrix and $I$ is identity matrix. Is there an easy way to see why the following works to compute $f(A)$?

$$f(A)=\frac{1}{P(A)}=-\sum_{b \in \text{poles}(f)} \frac{1}{P'(b)}(b I - A)^{-1}$$

In particular, I'm wondering how to connect that formula to the contour integral definition of $f(A)$
$$f(A)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C f(z) (z I - A)^{-1}$$

Following Dobrushkin [tutorial](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch1/resolvent.html), he shows that we can express that contour integral as a sum over residues

$$f(A)=\sum_{\alpha \in \lambda(A)} \text{Res}[f(\alpha) (\alpha I - A)^{-1},\alpha]$$

However, the above formula shows that instead of evaluating residues at eigenvalues of $A$, we can evaluate them at poles of $P$, and flip the sign.

$$f(A)=-\sum_{b \in \text{poles}(f)} \text{Res}[f(b) (b I - A)^{-1},b]$$

Below I verify that these formulas work for the following values of $f$ and $A$:

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{t^4}{24}+\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^2}{2}+t+1}$$

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 4 & 16 \\
 18 & 20 & 4 \\
 -12 & -14 & -7 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Why do these formulas work? The [resolvent method](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch1/resolvent.html) supposedly only applies to entire functions, and $f$ is not such

**Edit**

It appears we can compute $f(A)$ by either integrating $f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}$ counter-clockwise around poles of $(zI-A)^{-1}$ (**blue** circles) or clockwise around poles of $f(z)$ (**red** circles). The first one gives representation of $f(A)$ in terms of partial fractions, the second gives Dobrushkin's "resolvent" [method](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch1/resolvent.html)

Let $$f(t)\frac{t+3}{\frac{t^2}{2}+t+1}$$

$$A=5$$

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

poly = 1 + t + t^2/2 + t^3/6 + t^4/24 // N;
Print[poly];
dpoly = Function @@ {{t}, D[poly, t]};

f[t_] := Evaluate[1/poly];
f[A_List] := MatrixFunction[t |-> Evaluate[1/poly], A];

A = {{1, 4, 16}, {18, 20, 4}, {-12, -14, -7}};
truth = f[A];

(* following Dobrushkin resolvent method *)
ii = IdentityMatrix[Length@A];
resolvent[s_] := Inverse[s ii - A];
resolventResidue[eig_] := Simplify[(s - eig) resolvent[s]] /. s -> eig;
truthDobrushkin = 
  Total@Table[f[eig] resolventResidue[eig], {eig, Eigenvalues[A]}];

Print["Dobrushkin method works: ", truth == truthDobrushkin];

(* Rational approximation method *)
roots = t /. {ToRules@Roots[poly == 0, t]};
truthRational = -Total[1/dpoly[#] resolvent[#] & /@ roots];
Print["Rational approximation method works: ", 
 truth == truthRational]
```

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-dobrushkin-vs-rational.nb)

Comment: Isn't it obtainable from the Lagrange interpolation formula as you can see it on dia 46 of this very interesting [document](https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/talks/funm03.pdf) of N. Higham ?

Comment: Interesting, that formula does look similar, although it doesn't say what is "confluent div. diffs."

Comment: See for example [this document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265702047_Divided_Differences_and_Combinatorial_Identities) especialy prop 5.1 p.19.

Comment: Not clear to me how it follows from Lagrange formula, but it looks almost identical to formula 8 of [Dobrushkin](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch1/resolvent.html). The main difference is that instead of summing over eigenvalues of $A$, the sum is performed over poles of $f$. Either sum appears to give the correct answer

Comment: Indeed, it's the right way to see it : reversing from roots to poles. The reference to Dobrushkin you have given is interesting. I didn't know his name.

Comment: The function $f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}$ has singularities both at eigenvalues of $A$ and at poles of $f$....why are we free to choose one set, shouldn't the sum be done over all singularities?

Comment: I think that it is valid only for $f$ holomorphic, therefore without poles.

Comment: Right, that's what the tutorial says. However, I have checked that both formulas give correct result for f defined as 1 over polynomial, hence not holomorphic. Updated post with values of $f$ and $A$ I used to check

Comment: @JeanMarie updated with some visualization. It appears these two different formulas come out of different choices of contours when integrating ()(−)−1
. The first choice of contour corresponds to Cauchy's integral formula, not sure about the second one

Comment: [+1] Remarkable ! Thank you for this very didactic explanation. Therefore there is no need for Lagrange interpolation formula neither for divided differences...

Comment: In fact, you could transfert your edit into an answer to your own question.

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't fully understand the second method though -- getting f(a) by integrating f(z)/(z-a) over poles of $f$ clockwise, why does it work? Is it reducible to Cauchy's theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma.**  *The sum of all residues of a **rational function** $R(z)= A(z)/B(z)$ is zero if the denominator degree is at least 2 more than the numerator.*

Proof. [Sum of residues of rational function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824918/sum-over-all-residues-is-zero)

**Proof of the principle**.

For the examples you have given, $f(z)=\frac{1}{P(z)}$ is a **rational function** whose denominator degree is at least one more than that of its numerator, and therefore the matrix-valued expression $ R(z)=\frac{ f(z)}{ zI - A}$  satisfies the hypothesis of the lemma (entry-wise). There are two types of residues in the latter expression: (a) those
associated to the eigenvalues of $A$, and (b) those associated to the poles of $f(z)$, which below I will designate by the letter $b$.  By the lemma,  the sum of residues of type (a), which equals $ f(A)$, is minus the sum of  the other residues: $-\sum _b \frac{ 1}{ P'(b) } \frac{ I}{ b I- A}$.

Comments.

(i) The lemma hinges on estimating the rate of decay of a contour integral taken over a large loop. If $f(z)$ is not rational, then the desired decay estimates are unlikely to be fulfilled.

(iii) If by chance any of the poles of $f(z)$ overlap the eigenvalues of $A$ then I suspect everything needs to be re-analyzed from scratch.

Comment: Interesting!  I've fixed notation, $A$ refers to matrix, $a_i$ refers to poles of both kinds

Comment: Sorry to nitpick. I fear that is also confusing. Perhaps the poles of f could be called "b" and the eigenvalues of $A$ called $\alpha$?

Comment: Fixed. It's interesting that this contour integral is so specific to rational functions. If I replace $1+t$ with $1+t^{1+\epsilon}$, the error of the second integral grows fairly fast with $\epsilon$, but then starts to drop again once $1+\epsilon$ approaches the next integer value

Comment: Where can I find proof of this lemma?

Comment: I added a link to proof. Also note that fractional exponents don't play well with analytic functions (they become multiple-valued  and require the use of  branch cuts.