# $|P(z)|\le r^n C$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I've found [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305531/residues-and-poles-proof/1305571#1305571) proof, first answer, using that $|P(z)|\le r^n C$ for all $|z|=r>1$ where $P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k$, $C=\max\{|a_0|,...,|a_n|\}$. I do not understand why that is true.

I only get $|P(z)|\le r^n(|a_0|/r^n+|a_1|/r^{n-1}+...+|a_n|)\le Cr^n(1/r^n+1/r^{n-1}+...+1)\le nCr^n$.

Comment: $$|P(z)|=|\sum a_kz^k|\le \sum|a_kz^k|\le \sum |a_k||z^k|\le r^nC$$

Comment: Thanks! How do you get the last inequality?

Comment: Because $r\gt 1$ so $r^{n+k}\gt r^n$ for $k\ge 1$

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this gives us the result? Actually I can't see any exponents greater than $n$ appear in the context.

Comment: I doubt that this inequality indeed holds. I think the bound is indeed $nCr^n$ which still does our job for the proof in the link.

Answer (score 0):

It was clarified in the initial [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305531/residues-and-poles-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1) that the correct bound is $nCr^n$ and not $Cr^n$.